# GLSL per pixel point light shading

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

**VC++, OpenGL, SDL**

I am wondering if there is a way to achieve smoother shading across a single Quad of geometry. Right now, the shading looks smooth with my point light, however, the intensity rises along the `[/]` diagonal subdivision of the face. The lighting is basically non-visible in-between vertices.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**This is what happens as the light moves from left to right**

As I move the light across the surface, it does this consistently. Gets brightest at each vertex and fades from there.

Am I forced to up the subdivision to achieve a smoother, more radial shade? or is there a method around this?

Here are the shaders I am using:

**vert**

```
varying vec3 vertex_light_position;
varying vec3 vertex_normal;

void main() 
{            
    vertex_normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    vertex_light_position = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz);

    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

**frag**

```
varying vec3 vertex_light_position;
varying vec3 vertex_normal;

void main() 
{
    float diffuse_value = max(dot(vertex_normal, vertex_light_position), 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color * diffuse_value;
}
```

My geometry in case anyone is wondering:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x, pos_y - size_y, depth);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x + size_x, pos_y - size_y, depth);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x + size_x, pos_y, depth);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(pos_x, pos_y, depth);
glEnd();
```

Comment: That image is very small. Can you put a big larger picture?

Comment: That's 1:1. I'll upload a series so it makes more sense.

Comment: Your shader appears to be using a directional light. Directional lights on a flat surface (without attenuation) should produce *uniform* lighting (the same light intensity at every point on the surface). Since that's not happening, something must be wrong.

Comment: @Headspin: Are you sure those shaders are actually bound and? It certainly looks like fixed-function illumination in the pictures.

Comment: Yah, I am positive they are being bound, just because I can copy/paste other working shaders of mine and see results. This does just look like the default functionality.

Comment: What happens if you write the normal as a color? Just do `gl_FragColor = vec4(vertex_normal, 1.0);`. The best way to debug shaders is to start writing values as colors and see whether what you get is reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things I see as being possible issues.

Unless I am mistaken, you are using `normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz);` to calculate the  light vector, but that is based solely on the position of the light, not on the vertex you are operating on. That means the value there will be the same for every vertex and will only change based on the current modelview matrix and light position. I would think that calculating the light vector by doing something like `normalize(glLightSource[0].position.xyz - (gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex).xyz)`  would be closer to what you would want.

Secondly, you ought to normalize your vectors in the fragment shader as well as in the vertex shader, since the interpolation of two unit vectors is not guaranteed to be a unit vector itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with light vector...

I suggest using:

```
vec3 light_vector = normalize(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - vertex_pos)
```

vertex_pos can be calculated by using:

```
vertex_pos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex
```

Notice that all the vectors should be in the same space (camera, world, object)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I forced to up the subdivision to achieve a smoother, more radial
>   shade? or is there a method around this?

No, you are free to do whatever you want. The only code you need to change is the fragment shader. Try to play with it and see if you get a better result.

For example, you could do this :

```
diffuse_value = pow(diffuse_value, 3.0);
```

as explained [here](http://www.cuboslocos.com/tutorials/OSG-Shader).